# Linq : copy a value to another

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a collection of this object :

```
public Class MyObject()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string NL { get; set; }
    public string FR { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have this

```
IList<MyObject> listObject = new List<Object>();
bool res = MyMethod();
```

I'd like depending of the res result copy all the value of FR to Value and from NL to Value if res is false :

I try this :

```
var res = (from p in listObject select new { Id = p.Id, Value = ??????  });
```

the ?????? reprsent the code I don't find :(

Any idea ?

Thanks,

**UPDATE1**
I made a more generic method :

```
  public void MyTest<T>(IList<T> list) where T : ILookup
    {

        bool res = MyMethod();
        var result = (from p in list select new { Id = p.Id, Value = res? p.FR : p.NL });
        return result;

    }
```

What is the return type ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [conditional or ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will help here. An example of how it work is:

```
var result = booleanExpression ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

applied to your code it would look something like this:

```
var copy = (from p in listObject select new { Id = p.Id, Value = res ? p.FR : p.NL});
```

If you wish the result to be returnable from the method you will have to use a class with your select statement rather than createing an anonymous type:

```
var copy = (from p in listObject select new MyObject { Id = p.Id, Value = res ? p.FR : p.NL});
```

where MyObject has properties defined as Id and Value. You could then return it as

```
IEnumerable<MyObject >.
```

Comment: It probably makes sense to call the collection variable something other than `res` though.

Comment: @Lasse - very valid point; didn't notice that in the original code.

Comment: Thanks see my update1. @Andy if you change "res" to "result", need to use "result" in the Linq part too :). Of course, it's not res in my code, but "res" (result) is shorter

Comment: What is the return type of copy ?

Comment: @Kris-I - copy will be a collection of anonymous objects created by the select new { Id= p.Id, ... You can use this within the scope of the method that creates it but you cannot return it from the method. If you want to make copy a returnable object you will need create objects using a class with your select statement i.e. select new MyObject (Id = p.Id, ... You can then return it as IEnumerable<MyObject>.

Answer (score 4):

Use the ternary operator

```
var result = (from p in listObject select new { Id = p.Id, Value = res ? p.FR : p.NL  });
```